# How do I use jQuery .each() to find a child's children?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Given many TABLE tags on a page, how do I select the TD childred on a selected table.

This is logical, but fails with this error:

```
Error: uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object Object]tr
```

My code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var selectedTable = $('table').eq('9');

    $(selectedTable).css('border','10px solid green');

    $(selectedTable + 'tr td').each(function(i) {
        $(this).css('border','10px solid blue');
    });

});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`selectedTable` is a jQuery object, not a string.
You can't use it in a selector.

Instead, you need to use jQuery's traversal API:

```
selectedTable.find('tr td')
```

Answer (score 25):

```
$(selectedTable).find('td').each(function (index, element) {
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
selectedTable.find('tr td').each(function(i) {
        $(this).css('border','10px solid blue');
    });
```

You can also chain like the following:

```
selectedTable.css('border','10px solid green').find('tr td').each(function(i) {
  $(this).css('border','10px solid blue');
});
```

Also, you don't need to use $(selectedTable) again as your selector already returns a jquery object.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to get the children of the table. The problem you're having is that `selectedTable` isn't a selector string, but an object. You can't concatenate an object with a string, which is why you get your error.

This should work fine:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var selectedTable = $('table').eq('9');

    $(selectedTable).css('border','10px solid green');

    $(selectedTable).find('tr td').each(function(i) {
        $(this).css('border','10px solid blue');
    });
});
```